# Table locking behaviour of SQL Server 2005 while extracting data from Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, linked-server, type-conversion

I am trying to understand a SQL Server behaviour in below case.

I am fetching around half million rows from Oracle into a SQL Server 2005 database using linked server created in SQL Server. I am using around 50 odd columns for a `Insert Into select` query.

I found that the query did not finish and it used to run indefinitly until I stop it manually. But after around 1 Hr if I check the destination table I was able to find the rows in the table. But neither did the query stop executing nor did it release exclusive lock on the desination table.

When I fired a simple query with the Oracle linked server, then I figured out that some of the datatypes from Oracle and SQL Server had be to explicitly converted (esp Oracle `numeric` to SQL Server `Varchar`).

After all the datatypes who had this issue were explicitly converted, I was able to finish this entire fetch with without any problems i.e. query stops normally and releases exculsive lock on the table.

The question I have is, why did the query fetch all data despite datatype conversion issues in query and why did it held the lock even after it fetch all the data? Any explanation to this would be higly appreciated (even though the problem is resolved :) )

Comment: Question: **WHY** are you storing a *numeric* value as a `varchar` in SQL Server?!?!? [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: I absolutely agree and thanks for the link you share, it was helpfull. But somehow I was not able to change the table datatypes due lot of dependencies on it. Even I was figuring out why it was designed that way. Aren't there datatype formats in Oracle which are not compatible with Sql Server datatypes

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL uses various locks, row, column, table. It probably escalated the lock to table. It will also update each relevant index on each row insert unless you tell it not to. There are two ways around this: Insert rows in batches: say 1000 or 10000, experiment to find a good batch size for your columns width. Or, disable the indexes (and remember to renable them). MSSQL will have to do all the type conversions in one for the entire select and will probably use tempdb or memory so if there are any limits there, this will also slow things down: memory swap file etc, but doing it in batches will elliminate this bottleneck. Also each insert will be an implicit transation, which for consistency SQL needs to be able to roll back... not to forget writng all this to log files.